# Where or Join Which one is evaluated first in sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-execution-plan

### **Query**

```
select * from TableA a join TableB b
on a.col1=b.col1
where b.col2 = 'SomeValue'
```

I'm expecting the server, first filter the col2 from TableB then do the join. This will be more efficient.

1. Is that the sql server evaluates the where clause first and then Join?
2. Any link the to know in which order sql will process a query ?

Thanks In Advance

Comment: Only the optimizer knows. http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/5038/sql-server-join-where-processing-order

Comment: Look at the execution plan.

Comment: There is a *logical* order in which clauses are evaluated, but the entire language is built around the concept that implementations are allowed to perform processing in other orders, so long as the *results* match those that would be achieved had the logical order been followed.

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/5038/sql-server-join-where-processing-order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Already answered ... read both answers ...

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/5038/sql-server-join-where-processing-order

To summarise: it depends on the server implementation and its execution plan ... so you will need to read up on your server in order to optimise your queries.

But I'm sure that simple joins get optimised by each server as best as it can.

If you are not sure measure execution time on a large dataset.

Answer (score 1):

We will use this code:

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#TableA',N'U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #TableA;
IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#TableB',N'U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #TableB;

CREATE TABLE #TableA (col1 INT NOT NULL,Col2 NVARCHAR(255) NOT NULL)
CREATE TABLE #TableB (col1 INT NOT NULL,Col2 NVARCHAR(255) NOT NULL)

INSERT INTO #TableA VALUES (1,'SomeValue'),(2,'SomeValue2'),(3,'SomeValue3')
INSERT INTO #TableB VALUES (1,'SomeValue'),(2,'SomeValue2'),(3,'SomeValue3')

select * from #TableA a join #TableB b
on a.col1=b.col1
where b.col2 = 'SomeValue'
```

Let`s analyze query plan in MSSQL Management studio. Mark full SELECT statement and right click --> Diplay Estimated Execution Plan. As you can seen on the picture below
[image: query plan]

**first it does Table Scan for the WHERE clause, then JOIN.**

*1.Is that the sql server evaluates the where clause first and then Join?*
**First the where clause then JOIN**

*2.Any link the to know in which order sql will process a query?*

**I think you will find useful information here:**

1. [Execution Plan Basics](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/performance/execution-plan-basics/)
2. [Graphical Execution Plans for Simple SQL Queries](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/performance/graphical-execution-plans-for-simple-sql-queries/)

Answer (score 1):

It's decided by the sql server query optmiser engine based on which which execution plan have lesser cost.

If you think that the filter clause will benefit your query performance, you can get the subset of the table by filtering it with your desired value and make a CTE for it.

Then join the cte expression with your other table.

You can check which query performs better in your case in SSMS and go with it :)